# jQuery Loop through text content while keeping wrapping html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript function that aims to append a BIDI code to text that matches a specific criteria.The problem with the current function is that it works great with text only content but is problematic with content that has HTML Content. To summarize, I am splitting the text into words and checking if any of the characters in each word is matching a certain criteria to append the BIDI code to it.

The current status:

```
<div>This is the text that I am processing</div> //This works great

<div><span>This is the text</span><p>that I am processing</p></div> // This doesn't work well.
```

I want the function to work is for the text but also to keep the wrapping HTML tags in their place in order to keep

etc....

```
function flipper(flipselector) {
        var pagetitle = $(flipselector);
        var text = pagetitle.text().split(' '); //I know that I am using text function here but .html didn't work either
        var newtext="";
    for( var i = 1, len = text.length; i < len; i=i+1 ) {
        //text[i] = '<span>' + text[i] + '</span>';
        newstring="";

        if (matches = text[i].match(/\d/))
        {
            var currentstring=text[i];
            for (var x = 0, charlen = currentstring.length; x < charlen; x++) {

                if (matches = currentstring[x].match(/\d/)) {
                    varnewchar=currentstring[x];
                }else {
                    varnewchar= "&rlm;" + currentstring[x];    
                }

                newstring=newstring + varnewchar;
            }

        } else {
            newstring= text[i];
        }

          newtext=newtext + " " + newstring;
    }
    pagetitle.html(newtext);
    }
```

Comment: What was the result of using .html() instead of .text()?

Comment: Hi Derek, if I use .html() and then the split function, most of the html tags are gone (<p></p><introduction></introduction>, etc. I am left with <br> and <b>. How can I keep all the tags that are wrapped with < > as is?

Comment: The code seems to work fine with .html() [here](http://jsfiddle.net/S8jgz/2/). Note: I changed the starting index of your outer for loop.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late reply. I have included an example at which the function fails to work properly with custom tags, <b> and <br> ... http://jsfiddle.net/S8jgz/3/ ....